# How to determine if NSString is empty

Tags: objective-c, iphone

What is the best was to determine if an NSString is empty?  Right now I am using the following:

`if (string == nil || [string isEqualToString:@""]) {
// do something }`

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
if ([string length] == 0) {
    // do something
}
```

If the string is `nil`, then the message to `nil` will return zero, and all will still be well.

Comment: +1 for your answer. what about whitespaces? What if you don't want to count them? Any handy way?

Comment: @cocoafan Not concisely. If you need to do that frequently, I'd suggest adding a category to `NSString`, something like `isNotEmpty`, that you can do your custom checks in. Then you can just do `if ([string isNotEmpty]) { … }` and it will also handle `nil`s properly…

Comment: You may still want to know why the length returned 0 so it might be useful sometimes to check for nil, after getting the zero.

Comment: You would want to check against a temp string created by splitting the string with componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterset whiteSpaceCharacterSet] then joining the resulting array of string components.

Comment: If you expect large strings or frequently not actually having whitespace, you could wrap that in a check for rangeOfCharactersFromSet to avoid an unnecessary array.

Comment: @JohnCalsbeek Please, no negatives in boolean getters! I hate to see code like `if (![string isNotEmpty]) {`. Better to name the method `isEmpty` or `isBlank`.

Comment: @Sulthan I completely agree with you, but being negative is important to this particular method, since messages to nil return `NO`. Maybe `hasValue` or something of that sort would be better.

Answer (score 2):

This will not only check if there is nothing in the string but will also return false if it is just whitespace.

```
NSString *tempString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];


if ([tempString length] != 0) {
    //There is something in the string.
} else {
    //There is nothing or it is just whitespace.
}
```

Comment: This only removes leading and trailing whitespace

Comment: You know what, you're right. I was doing a lot of experimentation and must have copied and pasted the wrong code. It's corrected. This is much more efficient.

Comment: Whatever else it might be, `-stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` is not especially efficient. Much better to test what you're actually looking for: non-whitespace characters. `!myString || [myString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] invertedSet].location == NSNotFound` (In this case, you have to test whether `myString` is `nil` explicitly because an `NSRange` resulting from messaging `nil` won't have `NSNotFound` in its `location` field.)

Answer (score 0):

Not good solving

`[nil length]` is `0`

`(0==0)` is `1`

then `([string length] == 0)` will be `1`. Although it is wrong.

The best way is

```
if (![string length]) {

}
```

Comment: length is a NUMBER and should be checked with == 0. if(![string length]) is a c hack and (semantically) not correct since ! should be used for booleans. Please don't tell that it still works. I know that. It is just neanderthalish.

Comment: This answer is wrong. !0 is 1 too, just the same as 0 == 0. The result is the same, the only thing that can be argued about here is a matter of style